# Convolution exponential uniform. Can anyone help please?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$, let Y be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$ independent of $X$. Find the probability density function of  $X + Y$

I know that this question has already an answer but I would like to know whether my solution is equivalent to the answers in this site,

My solution is:
$$
(f_X * f_Y)(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f_X(y) f_Y(x-y)\,dy & \text{if }x\ge1, \\[10pt]
\displaystyle\int_0^x f_X(y) f_Y(x-y)\,dy & \text{if }0 < x < 1, \\[10pt]
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$

But I always find written:
$$
(f_X * f_Y)(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \int_{x-1}^x f_X(y) f_Y(x-y)\,dy & \text{if }x\ge1, \\[10pt]
\displaystyle\int_0^x f_X(y) f_Y(x-y)\,dy & \text{if }0 < x < 1, \\[10pt]
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$

Are they equivalent? I think so, but can you help me to make sure this is the case?

This has nothing to do with the question mentioned, I am not referring to any change of variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Convolution of two rv with different distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459056/problem-with-convolution-of-two-rv-with-different-distribution)

Comment: My question ia different, I am trying to know whether my solution ia correct or not. I am not refferring to any change of variable. Why should they be related?

Comment: So are they related only because they refer to convolution?

Comment: "But I always find written:" -> where? If you take e.g., $x=2$, then $f_X(y)=0$ in the integral since $y\in [1,2]$, but $f_X$ is the density of a r.v. uniform on $[0,1]$. Where do you see that written?

Comment: You are right. Perhaps it is because moat of the answer call fx(y) the density of the exponential. So my answer shoumd be ok. Shouldn't it?